# Shared Primary Key between two Entities Not Working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have created two Entities namely Teacher and Detail, the code snippet is shown below

**Teacher.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Detail detail;

    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
//getter and setter
}
```

**Detail.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail")
public class Detail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Teacher teacher;
    @Column(name = "subjects")
    private String subjects;

    public Detail() {
    }

    public Detail(String subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
//getter and setter
}
```

I am trying to achieve one to one mapping with the shared primary key concept
but when i execute the controller, only Teacher table is updating with the value

```
try {
    Teacher teacher=new Teacher("xyz",23);
    Detail detail=new Detail("Java,c,c++");

    teacher.setDetail(detail);
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(teacher);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    model.addAttribute("added", "data inserted");
    session.close();
}
```

After executing only Teacher table is updated with the specified values.Detail table is still showing empty

Comment: Try the following: (a) Add `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` to the `Teacher.id` field. (b) Replace `@Id` on `Detail.teacher` field with `@MapsId`.

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work exactly like that. You still need the id field in your `Detail`, so add:

```
@Id
private long id;
```

to your `Deatail` class.

And - as comment suggests - replace the `@Id` annotation in field `Teacher` to `@MapsId`. This way the id of `Teacher` is mapped to the id of `Detail` BUT ONLY if you also set the teacher to the detail - you always need to set both sides of relationship - like:

```
teacher.setDetail(detail);
detail.setTeacher(teacher);
```